# Latest Nugets for Outlook REST API?

Tags: nuget-package, adal, outlook-restapi, azure-ad-msal

I want to send emails from my .NET 4.6.1 application using one of our organisation's O365 email accounts.  I'm wondering if there's a Nuget package which can help me.

[Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices/) looks a bit out-of-date, and the comments on the project page don't inspire confidence.

[Microsoft.Graph](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph) seems more recent, but its code samples use the pre-release [Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/), which it says isn't suitable for production.  Maybe I can use [Active Directory Authentication Library .NET (ADAL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt417579.aspx) instead in conjunction with Graph?

Answer (score 1):

The [graph library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph) is the official SDK. It is linked from the [official Samles and SDKs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/code-samples-and-sdks) page.

Even though the MSAL is described as pre-release on the [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/) page, the [Github project page](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet) describes the Nuget as being from the stable branch.

Your mileage with it may vary, however in my projects I haven't had any issues with the 1.0.304142221-alpha NuGet.

Someone from Microsoft could probably shed some light on it, perhaps come with an indication of a release date of a non-preview NuGet?

Answer (score 0):

For just sending mails, you can use System.Net.Mail like this:

```
var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(RECEIVER_MAIL_ADDRESS));
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(SENDER_MAIL_ADDRESS, SENDER_NAME);
mailMessage.Subject = SUBJECT;
mailMessage.Body = BODY; 
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

using (var smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587))
{
    var credential = new NetworkCredential
    {
        UserName = USERNAME,
        Password = PASSWORD,
        Domain = DOMAIN_OPTIONAL
    };

    smtp.Credentials = credential;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.TargetName = "";

    await smtp.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
}
```